# .Net Windows Forms Unable to Get Drag Drop Class Data

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, user-controls

I have checked the other SO answers to similar questions and none are similar to this problem.

I am doing a DragDrop from one form to another within the same application. I check that the receiving form (where the drop occurs) is getting the correct data like this:

```
private void editor_DragEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(ComponentModel)))
   {
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    Log("Component Model Data is Present");
    }
else
    Log("Component Model Data is NOT Present");
}
```

The `ComponentModel` data is present. Component model is a class which is contained within the dragged user control's Tag property.

However, I can find no way to get the actual `ComponentModel` data. If I use debugging I can get to it through non-public methods - so I know the data is there...

**Question**
How can I access the data within the `ComponentModel` class?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this is how you access the data:

```
 if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(ComponentSelectionControl)))
            {
                var csc = e.Data.GetData("IDA.Controls.ComponentSelectionControl");
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
                Log("Component Model Data is Present");


            }
            else
                Log("Component Model Data is NOT Present");
```

So I simply use GetData with a string containing the Fully Qualified Control that is being dropped. I can then access the Tag property as normal.